# How can I delete Docker images by tag, preferably with wildcarding?

Tags: docker

I have some automated processes that spew a bunch of Docker images tagged with meaningful labels.  The labels follow a structured pattern.

Is there a way to find and delete images by tag?  So assume I have images:

```
REPOSITORY                  TAG
junk/root                   stuff_687805
junk/root                   stuff_384962
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to do:  docker rmi -tag stuff_*

Any good way to simulate that?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Fun with bash:

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep stuff_ | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
```

Comment: why not: `docker rmi $(docker images | aws '$2~/stuff_/{print $1}') `

Comment: Any way this could work in a Makefile? Make doesn't seem to understand how to do this when I use `shell` or by itself.

Comment: you might need `--force` in case it complains containers in use

Comment: @BMW I think you mean "AWK" not "AWS" in your suggestion.

Comment: yes, its typo, that’s awk command

Answer (score 160):

Using only docker filtering:

```
 docker rmi $(docker images --filter=reference="*:stuff_*" -q)
```

- `reference="*:stuff_*"` filter allows you to filter images using a wildcard;
- `-q` option is for displaying only image IDs.

Update: Wildcards are matched like paths. That means if your image id is `my-company/my-project/my-service:v123` then the `*` won't match it, but the `*/*/*` will. See the [github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36196) issue for description.

Comment: This wildcard approach doesn't work for me in docker version 20.10.6

Comment: It works bit in a surprising way: the wildcard does not match the slash. I.e. if you want to match `abc/xyz:tag`, then you have to use `*/*`. The simple `*` won't match anything.

Comment: @GeneS, thank you. I've updated the answer. There is a github issue for that point.

Comment: I can confirm this works on 20.10.21.

Comment: I don't know if this is intended to be used on Linux only (It looks like bash shell syntax). Running the command on Windows returns an error stating that --filter is an unknown flag.

Answer (score 44):

You can also acomplish it using grep + args + xargs:

```
docker images | grep "stuff_" | awk '{print $1 ":" $2}' | xargs docker rmi
```

- **docker images** lists all the images
- **grep** selects the lines based on the search for "_stuff"
- **awk** will print the first and second arguments of those lines (the image name and tag name) with a colon in between
- **xargs** will run the command 'docker rmi' using every line returned by awk as it's argument

**Note:** be careful with the grep search, as it could also match on something besides the tag, so best do a dry run first:

```
docker images | grep "stuff_" | awk '{print $1 ":" $2}' | xargs -n1 echo
```

- **xargs -n1** the -n1 flags means xargs will not group the lines returned by awk together, but echo them out one at a time (for better readability)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explaination. I've yet to find another method more robust.

Comment: `docker images | awk '{print $1 ":" $2}'| grep ":stuff_"  | xargs docker rmi` will work more reliably

Answer (score 17):

only using docker

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q junk/root:*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep stuff | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Docker provides some [filtering](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/images/#filtering) which you can use with [labels](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/labels-custom-metadata/), but I don't see wildcard support.

```
docker images -f "label=mylabel=myvalue"
```

Furthermore to add labels to an image you must add the information to the `Dockerfile` with a `LABEL` command. I couldn't find a way to add labels to an image unless you changed the `Dockerfile` (i.e. couldn't find a commandline option), though you can add them to containers at runtime with `--label` and `--label-file` ([run docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/)).

Answer (score 1):

Done the Docker way:

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -f=reference='<image_name>:<tag_name>*' --format "{{.ID}}")
```

Replace with your `<image_name>` and `<tag_name>`.

Answer (score 1):

in docker version 20.10.20 linux I had to tell the path for the Repository with / as described in some comments, so here was my solution

Example of what I get when I do a  `docker image`

as you can see I need something to select the TAG, lets say: *delete everything related to feature 1*

```
REPOSITORY                             TAG                        IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
nexus-snapshot.bla.com/core/apple      6.6.1-feature_1-SNAPSHOT   82cb336f7ed1   2 months ago   1.11GB
nexus-snapshot.bla.com/core/orange     6.6.1-feature_1-SNAPSHOT   82cb336f7ed2   2 months ago   1.12GB
nexus-snapshot.bla.com/core/apple      6.6.1-feature_2-SNAPSHOT   82cb336f7ed3   8 hours ago   1.11GB
nexus-snapshot.bla.com/core/orange     6.6.1-feature_2-SNAPSHOT   82cb336f7ed4   8 hours ago   1.12GB
nexus-snapshot.bla.com/core/apple      6.6.1-feature_3-SNAPSHOT   82cb336f7ed5   1 hour ago   1.11GB
nexus-snapshot.bla.com/core/orange     6.6.1-feature_3-SNAPSHOT   82cb336f7ed6   1 hour ago   1.12GB
```

Solution:

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images --filter=reference="nexus*/*/*:6.6.1-feature_1*" -q) -f
```

Explanation:

**note** I will be using **...** instead of * to make more human readable, it means any character

1 - Between the brackets () the inner command is:

searching for nexus.../.../... **:** tag 6.6.1-feature_1.... which than will return the id for 82cb336f7ed1 and 82cb336f7ed2

2 - The id will be passed to the outer command `docker rmi {82cb336f7ed1, 82cb336f7ed2} -f` to force remove the images

Answer (score 0):

I would use the image id to remove the images, the tag being '1.2.3':

```
docker rmi $(docker images | awk '$2~/1.2.3/{print $3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this thread but taking a different approach, I built a tool that helps select images quickly to delete, https://github.com/ryuheechul/termimagenator.