# How to delete images on disk for Docker mac?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac

I see a lot of info on deleting Docker images and containers that are 'dangling/unused', but how can I delete images that aren't running as a container that I've downloaded using docker-compose -f my-compose-file.yaml?

When I exec 'docker system prune', and then run docker-compose again, I'm getting messages that the images already exist. I'm trying to remove all existing images from my system that were previously downloaded with 'docker-compose'.

Answer (score 4):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490229/how-can-i-delete-docker-images-by-tag-preferably-with-wildcarding) Post. It'll give you a good idea on how to deal with images. 
Or in short and general:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -aq)
```

Comment: This one seems to work, but after I exec this command and then do 'docker-compose -f my-compose-file.yaml up', there are messages in the console that say "pulling from <name of repo> ae79f2514705: already exists, 5ad56d5fc149: already exists..." etc. Why does it detect that these images already exist if I deleted them with the command?

Comment: Great that I could help!
Try running:
`docker rm $(docker ps -aq) -f` 
after the first one. This should clean up a little more and might already resolve this behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, none of these commands work for what I'm asking to do. Like I said in my previous post, when running 'docker-compose -f <yaml file> up, docker detects that images still exist. The console says "5ad56d5fc149: Already exists"

Comment: maybe because the previous docker rm command not succeed on the image. it will complaints like "Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "xxx" (must force) - container b59819d8837c is using its referenced image 8d0f2b719930"

Answer (score 2):

You can clean up docker artifacts by using the following command (depending on what you need to clean up):

```
docker container prune
docker image prune
docker network prune
docker volume prune
```

These commands support '-a' option that will delete all of the artifacts if specified (for example `docker container prune -a` will remove all the containers)

In case you need to clean up everything you may want to use:

```
docker system prune -a
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Docker and still learning it.. Why not try `docker image prune -a` for removing unused images which are not being referenced by any container, for details see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) . Although I think that your docker system prune should have worked.

Answer (score 1):

The description of docker system prune in the docs is very brief

> Remove unused data

Can you try running `docker system prune --all` which according to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#usage) removes all unused images, the options for --all flag

> `--all , -a` Remove all unused images not just dangling ones

You could also try using `docker image prune --all` which is used to delete only unused images, for more see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. After running all these commands, including @heldic recommendations, 'docker-compose up' is still detecting that images already exist.